# Migration conflict in existing Databases - EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

A developer has enables migrations in a project with an existing database.
Sometimes we get exceptions because the classes don't reflect the tables.
Sometimes there is class properties not mapped to the db, sometimes there isn't even the property but there is a field in DB.

So we have to add some field that allready are are in the database, change another, etc. It causes a lot of changes that couldn't happen.

Currently I'm applying just the insert in migration table to skip the changes, but that isn't the best approach.

How to deal with this situations?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to get everything synchronized and then stick to the code first work flow where changes are made in the model and propagated to the database via migrations. You can see model changes not in the database by adding a migration, you can see database changes not in the models by reverse engineering with EF Tools and comparing/replacing.

Comment: Yes, I realised it should be this way.
But when I say it, my manager say we don't have time to synchonise the models ¬¬
It could be a joke if wasn't the reality

Comment: You have to use Migrations. Besides, set migration configurations `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` and `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed`. Also configure Migrations `Up` and `Down` method inside. By the way, you can use **Code First Approach with Existing Database**. Search it and use to create models with existing database.